# Symfony2 Form config.yml set "required" false

Tags: forms, symfony, config

First is an exmaple, we can do this

```
framework:
    form:            true
    csrf_protection: false
```

(look at **csrf_protection**)

Or set it in formType (but better in config if we don't want do this in all forms we have)

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Eve\CommonBundle\Form\Entity\formLogin',
        'required' => false,
        //'csrf_protection' => false
    ));
}
```

My choice is declare this in config.yml. Now, it was an example, question is....

In FormType we have property such as

```
        'required' => false // disabling html5 check to test POST types
```

how can i set it in config.yml ?

ps: it doesn't work if i set it the same way as 'csrf_protection'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no option that disable html5 validation from the config file, check the reference manual (nothing references it) : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html

As it depends more of the view, you should add the valid html attribute "novalidate" to all your form templates and don't manage it in the form class (even if it's possible ^^) :

```
<form novalidate="novalidate"></form>
```

The navigator will not validate the required fields (compatible with all navigators !).
It solves easily your problems !

Comment: 'required' => false will solve my problem too, but i saw an answer - "there is no property for this in config.yml" thnx